# How to handle multiple radio buttons inside multiple divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have few input fields in a container and user can multiply these fields. I need to change the name of the input fields based on the container.

```
<div class="stations">
 <input type="radio" name="pp[prc][0][station][0][id]">
 <input type="radio" name="pp[prc][0][station][1][id]">
</div>
```

This is my HTML form.

```
$(".stations").each(function(sIndex){
//Loop thru all .station
  $("input:radio", $(this)).each(function(rIndex){
    //Loop thru all radio buttons inside that container and change their names accordingly
   $("input:radio", $(this)).attr('name','pp[prc]['+sIndex+'][stations]['+rIndex+'][id]');
  });
});
```

When I do this, for some reason when the user duplicated `<div class="station">` and its content the name of the radio buttons are not changed accordingly. Where do I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have some issues with the selectors. Try it like this:

```
//Loop through each .station
$(".stations").each(function(sIndex){

    //Loop through each radio buttons inside the container
    $(this).find("input:radio").each(function(rIndex){

        // Change the radio name attribute
        $(this).attr('name','pp[prc]['+sIndex+'][stations]['+rIndex+'][id]');
    });
});
```

[Working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/zzMgM/1/)

[Here's a jsFiddle with the names on the screen for quicker viewing.](http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/zzMgM/2/)

Answer (score 1):

You are using `$(selector, context)` and  input elements can't have children, you should code:

```
$(this).attr('name', '...');
```